# Are there big differences from SQLite to SQLiteJDBC?

Tags: sqlite, sqlitejdbc

Will I get support successful from SQLite users even using SQLiteJDBC?
(I know nothing about both)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would expect so, at least to a point. Keep in mind that SQLiteJDBC is just a driver. From [their site](http://www.zentus.com/sqlitejdbc/):

> SQLiteJDBC is a Java JDBC driver for SQLite. It runs using either a native code library 100% Pure Java driver based on NestedVM emulation.

So anyone using SQLite is going to need a similar driver for their language - be it Java, C#, Python, etc.

Answer (score 0):

If you use sqlitejdbc-v056.jar (they say they are about to release a new one soon) then you will need to make sure your problems are not JDBC related before you ask questions to the SQLLite team.
If you run the native/JNI version then you will get better performance, but you will also need to worry about installing native shared libraries (dlls in windows) on your clients' boxes.

When you use multiple pieces of software you always run into trying to get support from each one and the support from each team finger pointing to the other.

This is one of the benefits of using purchased software and paying for support.

Comment: I woudn't say that paying for support is always a good thing, sometimes stackoverflow is very best (self experience).

Comment: @Tom Brito - Depends how much you business means to the support company.

Comment: The bad is that. Small clients seems to mean almost nothing for some companies.

Comment: @Tom Brito - That is where the internet and bad publicity can be great equalizers.

Comment: In my experience, I think the sqlitejdbc-v056.jar jar breaks under a 64 bit JVM....